# How to get price from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, paypal

I'm on a problem for few time ! I've a payment thing, where I use AJAX (to change the price directly when the user change a select), but the problem is, I don't know how to get the price (and verify it's the good price) to insert into the paypal Payment ! I tryed session with PHP etc.. But the price value wasn't changing :/

Index.php:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 animated fadeIn">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 order-actual-rank">
                                <p>Rang actuel</p>
                                <img id="current_league_img" src="assets/img/tiers/silver.png" alt="Silver" class="order-rank-img">
                                <div>
                                    <select name="order-division-actual_league" class="form-control" id="actual_league" onChange="changeCurrentLeague(); getDivPrice()">
                                        <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
                                        <option value="Silver" selected>Silver</option>
                                        <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                                        <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
                                        <option value="Diamond">Diamond</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <select name="order-division-actual_division" onchange="getDivPrice()" id="actual_division" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="1">I</option>
                                        <option value="2">II</option>
                                        <option value="3">III</option>
                                        <option value="4">IV</option>
                                        <option value="5" selected>V</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 order-desired-rank">
                                <p>Rang désiré</p>
                                <img id="desired_league_img" src="assets/img/tiers/gold.png" alt="Gold" class="order-rank-img">
                                <div>
                                    <select name="order-division-desired_league" onchange="changeDesiredLeague(); getDivPrice()" id="desired_league" class="form-control" id="desired_league">
                                        <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
                                        <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
                                        <option value="Gold" selected>Gold</option>
                                        <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
                                        <option value="Diamond">Diamond</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <select name="order-division-desired_division" onchange="getDivPrice()" id="desired_division" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="1">I</option>
                                        <option value="2">II</option>
                                        <option value="3">III</option>
                                        <option value="4">IV</option>
                                        <option value="5" selected>V</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 order-division-order">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Division : <span id="division_infos"></span></li>
                                        <li>Prix : <span id="boost_price"></span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <select name="order-division-server" class="form-control" style="width: 100px; margin-top: 10px;">
                                        <option value="euw" selected>EUW</option>
                                        <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="getDivPrice()" id="order-duo" name="order-division-duo" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; vertical-align: top;">
                                    <label for="order-duo">Duo</label>
                                    <div id="paypal-button" class="form-paypal">
                                    </div><script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/checkout.js"></script>
```

```
console.log(data);
 paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

     style: {
        label: 'generic',
        size:  'small',    // small | medium | large | responsive
        shape: 'rect',     // pill | rect
        color: 'gold',     // gold | blue | silver | black
        tagline: false    
    },

    client: {
        sandbox:    'AYh_cbrBW8_Ic8QLBh_hXPLpzbzFqc4_ckRsnH3cZ60oxheTz3CdZOgxlPK4TMDBF-ZiUR4EomVHMAkx',
        production: ''
    },

    commit: true,

    payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'EUR' }
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

            alert("Payement effectué");
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

AJAX :

```
function getDivPrice() {
    var price = 0;
    var actual_league = document.getElementById("actual_league").value;
    var actual_division = document.getElementById("actual_division").value;
    var desired_league = document.getElementById("desired_league").value;
    var desired_division = document.getElementById("desired_division").value;
    var dataString = 'type=division&actual_league=' + actual_league + 
    "&actual_division=" + actual_division + "&desired_league=" + desired_league +
    "&desired_division=" + desired_division;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
        url: '/FoxBoost/assets/getprice.php',
        success: function (data) {
                var duoqstr = "";
                if (document.getElementById('order-duo').checked)
                {
                    data = data * 1.3;
                    duoqstr = " en Duo"
                    data = data.toFixed(2);
                }
                if(data == 0)
                {
                document.getElementById('boost_price').innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('division_infos').innerHTML = "Ce boost n'est pas possible.";
                document.getElementById('hidden_price').value = data;
                }else{
                document.getElementById('boost_price').innerHTML = data + " €";
                document.getElementById('division_infos').innerHTML = actual_league + " " + actual_division + " " + "->" + " " + desired_league + " " + desired_division + duoqstr;
                document.getElementById('hidden_price').value = data;
                }
        }
    });
}
```

getPrice.php

```
<?php

$tiers = array(
               "Bronze 5" => 0,
               "Bronze 4" => 1,
               "Bronze 3" => 2,
               "Bronze 2" => 3,
               "Bronze 1" => 4,
               "Silver 5" => 5,
               "Silver 4" => 6,
               "Silver 3" => 7,
               "Silver 2" => 8,
               "Silver 1" => 9,
               "Gold 5"   => 10,
               "Gold 4"   => 11,
               "Gold 3"   => 12,
               "Gold 2"   => 13,
               "Gold 1"   => 14,
               "Platinum 5" => 15,
               "Platinum 4" => 16,
               "Platinum 3" => 17,
               "Platinum 2" => 18,
               "Platinum 1" => 19,
               "Diamond 5"  => 20,
               "Diamond 4"  => 21,
               "Diamond 3"  => 22,
               "Diamond 2"  => 23,
               "Diamond 1"  => 24
               );

$costs = array(
               10,10,10,10,12,
               12,13,14,15,18,
               18,20,22,24,28,
               30,33,36,39,45,
               65,75,85,125
               );

if($_POST['actual_league'] != null && $_POST['actual_division'] != null && $_POST['desired_league'] != null && $_POST['desired_division'] != null) {
    $actual = $_POST['actual_league']." ".$_POST["actual_division"];
    $desired = $_POST['desired_league']." ".$_POST["desired_division"];

    foreach($tiers as $index => $key) {
        if($actual === $index) {
            $actual = $key;
        }
        if($desired === $index) {
            $desired = $key;
        }
    }

    $price = 0;
    if ($actual < $desired) {
        for ($i = $actual ; $i < $desired ; $i++) {
            $price += $costs[$i];
        }
        echo $price;

    }else{
        echo $price;
    }

}else{
    header('Location: /foxboost');
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't need a loop to find elements in an associative array. `$actual = $tiers[$actual];`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help, I made the change, thanks for help ^^ Have you any idea about how to get price on index.php to make it to paypal express Checkout ? ^^ Thanks !

Comment: I can't see any reason why this doesn't work. Use the Network tab of the browser console to see what parameters you're sending and what the response is.

Comment: No, it works, the problem is, I've to got into another javascript script the value of data (from app.js (AJAX) to index.php)

Comment: Isn't that what `document.getElementById('hidden_price').value = data;` does?

Comment: No, it don't works, I think I'll do 2 AJAX request, one for the price, one to change content, but I feel it's kinda stupid

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. What content are you trying to change? But if the AJAX request is returning the correct data, there's no reason why it shouldn't get put into the value correctly. Make sure there's nothing extra around the price.

Comment: Add `console.log(data);` to see what's coming back.

Comment: It works, When I go on select input, It changes the price, but the problem is : with paypal Express Checkout, there's a javascript thing to make a button to the payment, and in the setting of javascript, I've to set the price, and I need to do it in index.php (where is the button, selects etc..), so I need to get the price after each AJAX changement on my script javascript in index.php

Comment: Isn't `index.php` where you're running the above Javascript? You need to post more code so we can see the whole data flow.

Comment: Edited the index.php